# How to dump Chef attributes as JSON locally

Tags: ruby, export, chef-infra, dump

How can I dump the structure from Chef cookbook from `attributes/default.rb` on the machine with the source code?

Let's say, I have a cookbook source code. And all the recipes are executed on the target node. I would like to parse the `attributes/default.rb` which creates the `node.default` and alike, which is then merged to just `node` tree. And then print it as JSON.

Something along the lines of

```
  json = "#{Chef::JSONCompat.to_json_pretty(node.to_hash)}"
  File.open("/tmp/node-dump.json", 'w') { |file| file.write(json) }

  yaml = node.to_yaml
  File.open("/tmp/node-dump.yml", 'w') { |file| file.write(json) }

  file '/tmp/chef/node-dump2.json' do
    source json
  end
```

But I want it to happen locally.

Is there a way? Chef 12.21.26

Answer (score 0):

As with your last question, there is no such thing as “locally” in Chef. All execution of cookbook code happens on the instance being converged. What you probably want is something like `knife node show -l -fJ`, but that wouldn’t help with Test Kitchen since there is no Chef Server to query.